# Complex Conjugate in Trigonometric form

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry

> Show that the complex conjugate of $$z = r(\cos \; \theta + i\; \sin \; \theta)$$ is $$\bar{z} = r(\cos (-\theta) + i\; \sin (-\theta)).$$

What I have tried:

Say $z$ is a complex number $a + bi$. Then, its trigonometric form is $$r(\cos \;\theta + i\; \sin\; \theta)$$
Thus,
$$z = a + bi = r(\cos\; \theta + i\; \sin \;\theta)$$

And $\bar{z}$ is the complex conjugate of $z$. Then $\bar{z}$ is equivalent to $a - bi$ and its trigonometric form is $$r(\cos\; \theta - i\; \sin\; \theta)$$

I got stuck at this point. How come $r(\cos\; \theta - i\; \sin\; \theta)$ is equivalent to  $r(\cos (-\theta) + i\; \sin (-\theta))$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because $\cos(-\theta)=\cos(\theta)$ and $\sin(-\theta)=-\sin(\theta)$.

Comment: Correct, I almost forgot that one.

Answer (score 1):

The $\cos$ function is even, i.e. $\cos(-\theta)=\cos \theta$ and the $\sin$ function is odd, i.e. $\sin (-\theta) = -\sin \theta$.